# django query parameter with space

Tags: python, django, url, query-string

I have a URL that takes query parameters that might have spaces in them. I know it looks pretty simple, but my regex is not working for me.

Here's my URL pattern definition:

```python
url(
    r'^item_info_details_view/(?P<itemno>[\w \/&-]+)/$',
    'purchasing.views.item_info_details_view'),
```

The itemno could be a phrase such as `FAX MODEM` which contains a space.

However, when I pass such a parameter to it, the URL in my browser is

```
http://localhost/item_info_details_view/FAX%20MODEM/
```

And displays this debugging info:

```
Using the URLconf defined in urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$
The current URL, item_info/FAX MODEM/, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be the space, but the fact that you've got "item_info_details_view" in the urlconf but "item_info" in the actual URL.

Comment: Beautiful! You nailed it! Thanks a lot Daniel, I wish I could spot this silly mistake myself! Feel free to post your answer below and I'll accept it. So basically, adding ` ` as part of the url regex works, thanks a lot!

Comment: feel free to post an answer there and I'll accept it, thanks a lot Daniel! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seem to be the space, but the fact that you've got "item_info_details_view" in the urlconf but "item_info" in the actual URL.

(As written by @daniel-roseman)